# Not able to install app made using App studio Windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, installation

Initially I was able to install on my `lumia 620` apps made using app studio.
Now I'm getting the following error.

> "We haven’t been able to contact the Microsoft Corporation company account to make sure you can install this app. Make sure you’re connected to a mobile or WiFi network, and we’ll try again as soon as we can.
>   Unfortunately, it may take a couple of days before we can make that connection. If you continue to have trouble contact your company’s support person for help."

I'm in India and I'm using the same live account I used earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this : [How do I get my app on my Windows Phone device?](http://appstudio.windows.com/en-us/Home/howTo#device)

It explains in details all the steps you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Phone 8.1

As well as various 3rd party QR Code readers you can use, you can also use Bing vision by doing the following. Open your camera on your Windows phone. Press the “Lenses” button Search icon( Sometimes the lenses button won’t be bound to your screen, you can do this by pressing the three dots and adding it to your bindings ) From here, a new menu will appear with various lenses listed. Choose Bing Vision.

Remember that by clicking “install” you download the app. By clicking Tap to open, you add the company certificate. It pushes you back to “Install company app” at that point, but you do not have to do it a second time. At this point, go to your app menu and you will see your app. Point the phone’s camera at the QR code that opens with the certificate link, and the phone will automatically scan it. Click “add” and the certificate is successfully installed once it returns to the original Install the certificate page.
...... CAN'T UNDERSTAND THIS FULLY. PLEASE EXPLAIN